# How to clone a queue in python?

Tags: python

I have got a piece of code where I have a priority queue and I am trying to clone to traverse,

```
import Queue as Q

import copy

    q1 = Q.PriorityQueue()

    def printQueue(q):
        while not q.empty():
            print (q.get()),
        print ''

    q1.put((5,'s'))
    q1.put((2,'e'))
    q1.put((0,'a'))
    q1.put((0,'z'))
    printQueue(copy.copy(q1)) 
    print 'second'
    printQueue(copy.copy(q1))
```

I found on the web that I can do clone using copy.copy. However in my code, it is not working. When I call prinQueue for the second time, by that time the priority queue is empty. Could somebody point out what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Never heard of `PriorityQueue`s, but try `copy.deepcopy()` perhaps?

Comment: copy.deepcopy doesn't run on PriorityQueues.  Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377202/how-to-deepcopy-a-queue-in-python

Comment: Did you read the answer? To quote the link you gave `The queue module in Python is used for synchronizing shared data between threads. It is not intended as a data structure and it doesn't support copying (not even shallow copy).`

Comment: Generally, if you need to do anything other than  'put' and 'get', you shouldn't be using a queue.

Answer (score 6):

If you copy a queue, it doesn't work. You get back exactly the same object.

```
import Queue as Q
import copy
q1 = Q.PriorityQueue()
q2 = copy.copy(q1)
print repr(q2), repr(q1)

>> <Queue.PriorityQueue instance at 0x10568f2d8> <Queue.PriorityQueue instance at 0x10568f368>
```

From there, your printQueue statement actually depletes the `Queue`. That's why it's empty if you copy it again; you're copying an empty queue.

If you want to copy the queue, you can use `Q.get()` and `Q.put()`, or even `Q.queue` like so

```
q1 = Q.PriorityQueue()
## .. enter items

q2 = Q.PriorityQueue()
for i in q1.queue: q2.put(i)
```

But, you should read the other question, which has a couple of good answers! In particular, you may be looking for a data structure, that's `collections.deque` for example, not the synchronized `Queue`, intended for safe communication between `Threads`. See [how to deepcopy a queue in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377202/how-to-deepcopy-a-queue-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

Well, copy.copy just shallow copy.
As Charlie says, you can't do deep copy on PriorityQueues, but I found that since pq implemented by a queue, this might work for you:

```
q2 = Q.PriorityQueue()
q2.queue = copy.deepcopy(q1.queue)
printQueue(q1)
printQueue(q2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I did note when I needed to implement something similar was that .queue implemented a list of type (collections.deque). In my case I wanted to know how long the strings were in the list, in total, so I then just iterated on a copy of the .queue.

I likely could have iterated directly on _rxBuffer.queue, but rather, made a copy and worked on it.

```
    if _rxBuffer.empty():
        tempq = _rxBuffer.queue
        length = 0
        for x in tempq:
            length += len(x)
        print (length)
```

Comment: That's not a copy. You *are* iterating directly on _rxBuffer.queue.