# How do I deep copy the Queue in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

Let's take an example, I have two thread, in one thread, one Queue1 is busy with inserting but in other thread, I wanted to work with the items which are available in Queue1. For that, I think we need to have another Queue2 where we can copy the existing items in Queue1.

So, How would I copy the items from Queue1 so that Queue2 will not modify while working with it?

Motivation: Need to copy one queue to another where no modification should happen in copied Queue.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377202/how-to-deepcopy-a-queue-in-python would help you.