# Using asdict() on a dataclass with a queue.Queue() field throws TypeError

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

When making a dictionary out of a dataclass with a queue as one of the fields, python throws a TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

to reproduce the error the following code can be used:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import queue

@dataclass
class test:
    name:str = 'SomeString'
    data:int = 12345
    Que:queue.Queue = queue.Queue()

dataClass_obj = test()
dict_obj = asdict(dataClass_obj)
```

note that adding a queue to a dictionary normally does not produce any error.

I need to know how to include a queue.Queue() object in a dataclass, such that using the asdict method on the dataclass wont produce the TypeError.

Since the program uses dataclasses everywhere to send parameters I am keeping dataclasses here as well instead of just using a dictionary altogether.

Comment: `queue.Queue`s are kind of iffy, the first thing you should ask yourself when running into issues with them is "maybe I can use `collections.dequeue` instead?" See also [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377290/962190), since dataclasses are used as containers the same reasoning might apply to you here.

Comment: @Arne thank you for the suggestion. The deque object does work. 
Now, for communicating between two threads without the need for blocking, deque seems to be fine. when using pop left if you reach an empty deque it throws the index error. When appending, even if you use maxlen it wont throw an error, just remove items from the other end. Meaning that some coding is needed to raise an exception similar to queue.Full.
I will add a class implementing this feature as the answer to this thread shortly.

Comment: That's good to hear. Just to be sure - if you actually intended the queue for communication between threads, you might need to write your dataclass in way that the queue is shared between classes or instances. Meaning, the fact that dequeues are copied could lead to unwanted behavior.